# How can I create a friend system using AWS for Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

So I'm developing an app that requires for me to implement a friend system, in which permissions will be different amongst users who are "friends". I am using AWS Cognito for identity management, and DynamoDB for my database.

In my case, I will be granting view permissions only to confirmed friends of the user; you know, the standard run-of-the-mill friend settings. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to approach this? I am not entirely sure how to handle the issue of setting permissions for particular and individual users within my User Pool, especially in regards to particular and individual recipient users.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with user pools, but a bit tricky depending on specifics of your needs. You could do this with groups, but Cognito has limits on number of groups per pool (default is 25, but that's not a hard limit and can be increased via support).

If you need far more than that, you might want to create a mapping yourself, using the 'sub' value of a user pools user to identify a user. Alternatively, you could link it with federated identities, and use the identity id to identify a user. That would also help you get the AWS credentials to access this new mapping.